# Installing JDK to remote server

Tags: java, linux, jdk

I have been trying to install JDK to my online (remote) server.
I have never made such installation so kindly help what is an appropriate way to do it.
My doamin's hosting is linux.
There are tutorials available but i could not find any good for installation on linux based remote server.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have SSH access on remote server?

Comment: @satish I have access to domain's control panel : Hosted on godday :

Comment: Then you should ask question to your hosting support.

Comment: @Satish okay after getting that ACCESS what should i do next? (I'll get in a while)

Comment: generally they provide JDK, may be you just need to activate.

Comment: Do you know if you have can add PPAs?

Comment: @AdriánLópez Should i need SSH access for adding PPAs too? , Usually for remote server installation , packages provided like wordpress or the like and all you need to do is to upload that file and directly open that uploaded file's folder and installation being successfully made.

Comment: Yes you would need SSH

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to install a `Java JDK` to your shared hosting account. If you require Java JDK, you will need to consider the use of our `Virtual Dedicated Server` or `Dedicated Server` accounts for this functionality.

If you have dedicated server go ahead and use `apt-get` or `yum` to install `openjdk`

Comment: Thanks, I ask for SSH access and once i have it and got into trouble i'll let you know

Comment: Is this dedicated hosting or shared?

Comment: Its shared...... So i cannot install jdk right?

Answer (score 1):

The package manager should provide jdk if its not installed by default.

http://openjdk.java.net/install/

Comment: Do you think they will give root access on box?

Comment: He said its HIS server so yes.